# Calling array in twigs

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Unable to return the array of primary key (id) from entity resource into questionanswer twig .

QuestionAnswer template:

```
 {% for entity in entities %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ path('questionanswer_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ entity.question }}</td>
        <td>{{ entity.answer }}</td>
        <td>
            {% if entity.getResources is empty %}
                <p> </p>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ path('resource_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Yes</a>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
```

QuestionAnswer entity:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="resource", mappedBy="queId")
 */
private $resources;

/**
 * Get resources
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getResources() {
    return $this->resources->toArray();
```

Resouce Entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="questionanswer", inversedBy="resources")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="que_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $queId;
```

Comment: `resources` is a collection for QuestionAsnwer. Which means that at the very least you have to loop that collection is well.

Comment: Is that the exact error message that you get? And do you get the line number where the error was encountered in the twig file?

Comment: Error:  Unable to find resource entity.
It is taking question id instead of correct resource id

Comment: That is because you pass your question id as a parameter instead of looping over your collection items - `{{ path('resource_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}` here `entity` is still a reference to QuestionAnswer that you define in your `for` block. Read my first comment again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I understood your point but Can you please help me in telling me how can i loop the array collection of my resources in QuestionAnswer twig file :

//Resource entity :

 /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="questionanswer", inversedBy="resource")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="que_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $queId;